# Is that the general solution of the Helmholtz equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Helmholtz equation:

$$u_{xx}+u_{yy}+k^2u=0$$
$$0 \leq x \leq L$$
$$0 \leq y \leq L$$

The solution is in the form $u=X(x)Y(y)$

Replacing this at the equation we get the following problems:

$$X''+k_x^2X=0, X(0)=X(L)=0$$
$$Y''+k_y^2Y=0, Y(0)=Y(L)=0$$

We get that:
$$X_m=\sin{(\frac{m \pi x}{L})}, Y_n=\sin{(\frac{n \pi y}{L})}$$

So $u_{m,n}=X_m(x)Y_n(y)$
$$u_{m,n}(x,y)=\sin{(\frac{m \pi x}{L})} \sin{(\frac{n \pi y}{L})}, m,n=1,2,3, \dots$$
where $k_{m,n}^2=\frac{(m^2+n^2) \pi^2}{L^2}$

Could you tell me if $u_{m,n}(x,y)=\sin{(\frac{m \pi x}{L})} \sin{(\frac{n \pi y}{L})}, m,n=1,2,3, \dots$ is the general solution of the Helmhotz equation, or does the general solution contain also a sum??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the equation is *linear*, you must sum up your solutions.

Comment: So is the solution as followed?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}{c_{n,m}\sin{(\frac{n \pi y}{L})} \sin{( \frac{ m \pi x }{L})}}}$$

Comment: Yes. To be rigorous, you should prove that no different solutions exist.

Comment: How could I prove this?

Comment: You should prove that the functions you found form a basis of the solution space. It is not trivial, however.

Comment: And something else... How can I find $c_{n,m}$??

Comment: You can't. You are solving a linear equation, so the general solution is not unique. *Any* linear combination is a solution.

Comment: A ok!!! Thank you!!! :-)